# Слово "обезьяна"

Tags: этимология

Откуда в русском языке взялось слово "обезьяна"? В других языках, даже в славянских, она называется иначе, например, в украинском это"мавпа".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это слово появилось примерно в XVII веке путем слияния персидского слова "бузинэ" и старорусского "опица".

Comment: > персидского слова "бузинэ" и староруского "опица"
> 

что эти слова означают?

Comment: Обезьяна..

Answer (score 1):

Здраствуйте! Мне бы хотелось узнать, откуда в русский язык пришло слово "обезъяна" Это слово отсутствует в словаре Даля. Значит, в русской разговорной речи XIX в. это слово не употреблялось. В славянских языках этого слова тоже нет: по-польски "обезъяна"-"мавка". В других языках: -по-французки: singe -по-немецки: Affe Так где же наша обезъяна?

Ответ
Действительно, слово обезьяна - только русское. В других славянских языках это животное называется иначе (например, в чешском - opice, это слово родственно немецкому Affe; в польском małpa (от нем. Maulaffe - "зевака", "разиня", дословно "обезьянья пасть"), откуда и украинское мавпа, болгарское малпа.). В русском языке слово обезьяна известно, по крайней мере, с XVI века и, возможно, пущено в обращение Афанасием Никитиным. В словаре Даля (начиная со второго издания) это слово есть, и это первая словарная фиксация обезьяны. Это слово восходит персидскому бузинэ с тем же значением - слову, как полагают некоторые языковеды, арабского происхождения. В древнерусском языке обезьяна называлась так же, как ее сейчас называют чехи - опица. Под влиянием этого слова, а также словообразовательных моделей на -ан (а), -ян (а) (типа *поляна*) бузинэ и преобразовалось в обезьяна. Преобразование шло таким образом: обузина > обозина > обизина > обезияна > обезьяна.

gramota.ru

Comment: >в польском małpa (от нем. Maulaffe - "зевака", "разиня", дословно "обезьянья пасть"), откуда и украинское мавпа, болгарское малпа.).

Видел в одной старой (около 100 лет) украинской книжке написание *"малпа"* вместо современного укр. *"мавпа"*. Даже не сразу понял, о чём речь.

Comment: Да, за 100 лет украинцы придумали и переняли тысячи слов, которых явно не хватало в народных говорах Южной Руси, а уж историю полностью обновили.

Answer (score 0):

А я в отрывном календаре читала историю этого слова... Якобы ещё французы в 1812 году для общего обозрения привезли клетку с обезьяной и поставили на главной площади, ещё охранял солдат француз. Ну а поскольку народ наш простой любопытен до экзотики и рад повеселиться, то и окружили клетку и всякие прикормки туда бросали, дразнили всяко... А еще и спрашивали как, мол, зверя этого зовут... А солдат этот французский хоть и по-русски ни бельмеса не понимал, но так как  стоял на страже, то и отгонял зевак, как и было велено начальством, по-своему крича им "обизьен!" - типа отгоняя от клетки... Ну, а народ же ушлый у нас - так и дали якобы" заморскому зверю" имечко - "обезьян", а позже обезьяна.
Может такое быть, кто знает?

Comment: Все врут календари! (С)